# Get Position of Childnode in Xcode SceneKit editor

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I have a model of a car in Xcode SceneKit editor.[image]

Its wheels are subnodes of that car, which means their positions are relative to the car's position. However, all four wheels have `0` for `x,y and z`. So there must be an offset between the origin, and the cars defined somewhere (yellow lines in image). How can I get these?

Comment: If you know the origin point (red dot) position, you can then calculate the vertical yellow line because you must know the height of your wheel (so it's the radius). For the distance between the wheel and the origin, I have no idea.

Comment: Looks like the .pivot is set to something other than 0,0,0